# How to properly parse decoded base64 data

Tags: aws-lambda, base64, aws-api-gateway

I using AWS API Gateway, Lambda, and S3 for this implementation.
I am trying to update .png file to S3 bucket. I am using postman for this. API gateway convert the picture body into base64, when i decode the body it looks like this:
`` b'----------------------------724227124660663367109381\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="floorplan"; filename="PNG-Image.png"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\xcf\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x9b\xa8E\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x0e\xc3\x00\x00\x0e\xc3\x01\xc7o\xa8d\x00\x00\x00 cHRM\x00\x00z%\x00\x00\x80\x83\x00\x00\xf9\xff\x00\x00\x80\xe9\x00\x00u0\x00\x00\xea`\x00\x00:\x98\x00\x00\x17o\x92_\xc5F\x00\n\xed\x8cIDATx\xda\xec\xfdgTU\xd9\x82\xe8}\xcf\xb5\x03\xc9\\\xc9\xcaV\xce\xa7NE\xcb\xd22+(ADE\xcc9\x12$\x83\nFD\x11DE\x92\n\x98E\xc5\x08\x06@\x10A\x82D\x11P\x04\x11\xcc\x82\x82....... ``
not sure how to extract other information like Content-Disposition, name, filename etc.
this is what my code look like. it is for post.

```
parameters = event.get('queryStringParameters')
        project_name = parameters.get('project_name')
        body_decoded = base64.b64decode(event["body"])
        s3.put_object(Bucket='bucket_name', Key=f'{project_name}/floorplan_name.png', Body=body_decoded)
```

it upload the file in s3 but i get this error 
`The file “floorplan_name.png” could not be opened. It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.`

[image: my postman headers]

this is the payload i have.
[image: my payload]

Comment: What's the payload you are POSTing from Postman?

Comment: Body is form-data as picture file with .png

Comment: You need to use a library like [requests-toolbelt](https://pypi.org/project/requests-toolbelt/) to parse the form and get image payload. Why not POST just the image which can save you some trouble?

Comment: I can not just send the image if do I get 400. It required headers.